# application/octet-stream after spring boot update

Tags: angular, multipart, openapi-generator, spring-boot-3

Upgrading from Spring Boot 2.7.4 to 3.1.5 might have caused changes affecting media type handling. The error 'org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported' suggests an issue related to this content type.

I have a angular frontend and use opena pi generator 7.0.0 to generate my files:

```
    /testdimension/file-upload:
      post:
        tags:
          - TestDimension
        operationId: addFilesToTestExecution
        summary: Send files and IDs to the backend
        requestBody:
          required: true
          content:
            multipart/form-data:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  toolId:
                    type: integer
                    format: int64
                  ids:
                    type: array
                    items:
                      type: integer
                      format: int64
                    description: test dimensions array
                  files:
                    type: array
                    items:
                      type: string
                      format: binary
                    description: test files to upload
                required:
                  - ids
                  - files
        responses:
          '200':
            description: OK
          '400':
            description: Invalid request payload
          '500':
            description: Internal server error

this is my open api yml file. Befor the update everything worked fine. I tried to change the content type in the yml file but nothing changed. Also tried to enable  octet-stream in the spring configuration but didnt changed anythisng. is the error from the frontend or backend?

My spring class generated:
@Operation(
    operationId = "addFilesToTestExecution",
    summary = "Send files and IDs to the backend",
    tags = { "TestDimension" },
    responses = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Invalid request payload"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal server error")
    }
)
@RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    value = "/testdimension/file-upload",
    consumes = "multipart/form-data"
)
default ResponseEntity<Void> addFilesToTestExecution(
    @Parameter(name = "ids", description = "test dimensions array", required = true) @RequestPart(value = "ids", required = true) List<Long> ids,
    @Parameter(name = "files", description = "test files to upload", required = true) @RequestPart(value = "files", required = true) List<MultipartFile> files,
    @Parameter(name = "toolId", description = "") @RequestParam(value = "toolId", required = false) Long toolId
) {
    return getDelegate().addFilesToTestExecution(ids, files, toolId);
}
```

My Angular app generated:

```
/**
     * Send files and IDs to the backend
     * @param ids test dimensions array
     * @param files test files to upload
     * @param toolId 
     * @param observe set whether or not to return the data Observable as the body, response or events. defaults to returning the body.
     * @param reportProgress flag to report request and response progress.
     */
    public addFilesToTestExecution(ids: Array<number>, files: Array<Blob>, toolId?: number, observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: undefined}): Observable<any>;
    public addFilesToTestExecution(ids: Array<number>, files: Array<Blob>, toolId?: number, observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: undefined}): Observable<HttpResponse<any>>;
    public addFilesToTestExecution(ids: Array<number>, files: Array<Blob>, toolId?: number, observe?: 'events', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: undefined}): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>;
    public addFilesToTestExecution(ids: Array<number>, files: Array<Blob>, toolId?: number, observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: undefined}): Observable<any> {
        if (ids === null || ids === undefined) {
            throw new Error('Required parameter ids was null or undefined when calling addFilesToTestExecution.');
        }
        if (files === null || files === undefined) {
            throw new Error('Required parameter files was null or undefined when calling addFilesToTestExecution.');
        }

        let headers = this.defaultHeaders;

        let httpHeaderAcceptSelected: string | undefined = options && options.httpHeaderAccept;
        if (httpHeaderAcceptSelected === undefined) {
            // to determine the Accept header
            const httpHeaderAccepts: string[] = [
            ];
            httpHeaderAcceptSelected = this.configuration.selectHeaderAccept(httpHeaderAccepts);
        }
        if (httpHeaderAcceptSelected !== undefined) {
            headers = headers.set('Accept', httpHeaderAcceptSelected);
        }

        // to determine the Content-Type header
        const consumes: string[] = [
            'multipart/form-data'
        ];

        const canConsumeForm = this.canConsumeForm(consumes);

        let formParams: { append(param: string, value: any): any; };
        let useForm = false;
        let convertFormParamsToString = false;
        // use FormData to transmit files using content-type "multipart/form-data"
        // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data
        useForm = canConsumeForm;
        if (useForm) {
            formParams = new FormData();
        } else {
            formParams = new HttpParams({encoder: this.encoder});
        }

        if (toolId !== undefined) {
            formParams = formParams.append('toolId', <any>toolId) as any || formParams;
        }
        if (ids) {
            if (useForm) {
                ids.forEach((element) => {
                    formParams = formParams.append('ids', <any>element) as any || formParams;
            })
            } else {
                formParams = formParams.append('ids', ids.join(COLLECTION_FORMATS['csv'])) as any || formParams;
            }
        }
        if (files) {
            if (useForm) {
                files.forEach((element) => {
                    formParams = formParams.append('files', <any>element) as any || formParams;
            })
            } else {
                formParams = formParams.append('files', files.join(COLLECTION_FORMATS['csv'])) as any || formParams;
            }
        }

        let responseType: 'text' | 'json' = 'json';
        if(httpHeaderAcceptSelected && httpHeaderAcceptSelected.startsWith('text')) {
            responseType = 'text';
        }

        return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${this.configuration.basePath}/testdimension/file-upload`,
            convertFormParamsToString ? formParams.toString() : formParams,
            {
                responseType: <any>responseType,
                withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
                headers: headers,
                observe: observe,
                reportProgress: reportProgress
            }
        );
    }
```